# How can I use Dask in a non-DRMAA, batch-scheduled environment?

Tags: dask

I'd like to use dask-distributed, both for supported algorithms and for general task graph execution.  Unfortunately, the batch scheduler we use doesn't support DRMAA so I can't use dask-drmaa.  We have NFS available to all hosts.  Is there a way I can start using Dask or do I need to get DRMAA supported by the batch scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your batch scheduler to run the `dask-scheduler` and `dask-worker` processes, which are just normal python processes.  Because you have a shared network file system (NFS), this should be particularly easy.

Use your batch scheduler to run the following command

```
dask-scheduler --scheduler-file /path/to/some/new-file.json
```

Also use your batch scheduler to run the following command many times

```
dask-worker --scheduler-file /path/to/some/new-file.json
dask-worker --scheduler-file /path/to/some/new-file.json
dask-worker --scheduler-file /path/to/some/new-file.json
```

The scheduler and workers will coordinate their locations by that file and synchronize with each other.

You can then connect to this cluster from any Python session on the same network with the following commands

```
>>> from dask.distributed import Client
>>> client = Client(scheduler_file='/path/to/some/new-file.json')
```

Further information can be found here: http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html#using-a-shared-network-file-system-and-a-job-scheduler